# User are in unnamed module of loader 'app' in Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

I am newbie in Java Spring Boot and try to learn Spring Security. I have developed a project in this  and encounter with this error when login:
class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy107 cannot be cast to class com.security.domain.User (com.sun.proxy.$Proxy107 and com.security.domain.User are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
My UserService Class :

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    public void add(User user) {
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        user.getRoles().add(Role.USER);
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> findAll() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteById(Integer userId) {
        userRepository.deleteById(userId);
    }
```

and my config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;



    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        //NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
                .debug(true)
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/h2-console/**", "/css", "/swagger");
    }



    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/register/**")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/")
                .authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/delete/**")
                .hasAuthority(Role.ADMIN.getAuthority())
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin();
    }
}
```

This error appear when My username is correct. How can I solve this problem?